# Create function with vector input and vector output

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

I am new to Mathematica and am trying to create a function that will help me investigate a theoretical question. I will give you a sample of what I am trying to accomplish but really am just asking for links to tutorials or references that will help me get there.

The input to the function is a vector (I guess in Mathematica, a "list"). The function will perform some manipulations on the elements (components) of the vector and display another vector (same dimension). For example, if the vector

$\qquad v = (v(1),v(2),v(3),v(4),v(5),v(6),v(7))$,

I might want the function $f$ to produce a vector

$\qquad f(v) = (v(4)+v(5)-2v(1)-v(2)-v(3), v(2),v(3),v(4),v(5),v(6),v(7))$

(this is simplified, but you get the point).

I don't know where to start to learn how to define this. I'm sure it's simple, I just can't seem to put my finger on it in the labyrinth that is Mathematica documentation. I've tried "Googling" "mathematica pure vector function", "mathematica define function with vector input and output", etc. Doesn't help.

Any links or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [this introduction](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/)

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!